# Getting tooltips to render using tooltipster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltip, tooltipster

I've been banging my head against the computer for the past couple hours as to how to customize tooltips using [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#getting-started).  I'm currently doing:

head of index.html:

```
<head>

  <!--TOOLTIP CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="node_modules/tooltipster-master/css/tooltipster.css">

  <!-- JQUERY -->
  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <!-- TOOLTIP SCRIPT -->
 <script src="node_modules/tooltipster-master/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>

  <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.my-tooltip').tooltipster({
        theme: 'tooltipster-noir'
      });

    });

  </script>
</head>
```

body of index.html:

```
  <div class="my-tooltip" title="the message i want to tooltip out">Hover over me!</div>
```

The thing is that this still gives me the very basic tooltip without any color/theme/position changes.  If you all have any experience with this, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: You need to add tooltipster-noir.css -> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.0.5/css/themes/tooltipster-noir.min.css see your code working -> http://jsfiddle.net/pj93eswz/

Answer (score 2):

You haven't loaded the css files - tooltipster.css

Comment: Thanks for letting me know -- I accidentally forgot to add the CSS sheet in the head.  Just did.  The example still is not working as I want, however.

Comment: @Patryk - didn't quite understand. The problem in the question was "The thing is that this still gives me the very basic tooltip without any color/theme/position changes". Why wouldn't it "have been" a possible answer. Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings : Sorry you might be actually right. My bad.